# phpmyadmin: database events

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to move records from one table (upcoming) to another table (today) when the date of the record (from upcoming) equals today's date. How would I go about doing so using recurring events in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Why not have one table, and some partitioning?

Comment: I was more curious to see if it was possible to do what i asked (i'm mostly a beginner) than caring about simplicity. You are right though!

Comment: What you suggest/plan is a bad architecture. It makes things overly complex without offering any real benefit. You want to think that over again.

Comment: To answer your question: there are no such events, so there is nothing you can react to. You would have to poll for a date comparison on a regular base. _Really_ a bad idea :-)

Comment: Alright, thank you for the information !

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can use a MySQL event that runs at (actually shortly after) midnight each day. You can do whatever you want in that event. Here's an example.

```
CREATE EVENT `midnight_event`
    ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-10-10 00:00:00'
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    DISABLE ON SLAVE
    DO BEGIN

     START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT 
      INTO todays_table 
    VALUES (col, col, col, col)
    SELECT col, col, col
      FROM pending_table
     WHERE time_stamp >= CURDATE()
       AND time_stamp <  CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;

    DELETE 
      FROM pending_table
     WHERE time_stamp >= CURDATE()
       AND time_stamp <  CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;

    COMMIT;
END
```

Others have commented about the wisdom of this sort of data design, with rows moving from table to table.  There's considerable merit in their comments. If you want a "table" with today's events in it, consider a view.  This one will look just like the table you maintain with the event I mentioned.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW todays_table AS
SELECT *
  FROM pending_table
 WHERE time_stamp >= CURDATE()
   AND time_stamp <  CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```